# ebay and bootstrap: collapse menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As someone probably know - eBay doesn't respect eg. jQuery. I want make responsive template with responsive menu, but I don't known what should I do with menu. I must delete all jQuery from bootstrap and now menu toggle doesn't work on eg. smartphones. What should I do?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-headerOne">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#payments">Payments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#shipping">Shipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#returns">Returns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gurantee">Gurantee</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Abous us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create these menus without javascript you have to use some CSS. Maybe this link will help you for similar problems: [bootstrap-without-jquery](https://github.com/tagawa/bootstrap-without-jquery)

Here is a solution for your particular problem:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    /* Dropdown without JS */
    .dropdown-toggle:focus {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .dropdown-toggle:focus + .dropdown-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        opacity: 0;
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: visibility 0.5s;
    }
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:absolute;right:0;">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/menu1/">menu1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/menu2/">menu2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a href="/menu3/">menu3 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="/menu3/submenu1/">submenu1
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="/menu3/submenu2/">submenu2
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"
               style="background: white; padding-left: 50px;">App</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="/menu1/">menu1
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="/menu2/">menu2
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">menu3
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class=""><a href="/menu3/typ/A/">A</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/menu3/typ/B/">B</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/menu3/typ/C/">C</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="/menu3/typ/D/">D</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="/menu3/submenu1/">menu3
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <i class="navbar-text navbar-right">
                <a href="/logout" style="">Logout</a>
            </i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```